# What is angle alpha

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

In right triangle:

[image]

Taken from: https://xaktly.com/MathNonRightTrig.html

We have side $a=2c_1$. Where $c_1$ is a perpendicular projection of c onto b.
What is the angle A?
I have tried solving using quadratic equation obtained from solving for height.

But, it fails, giving a bit incorrent answer. I think the reason may be that I may have solved the equation wrongly, or tried it in a wrong way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In which variables are you supposed to express A? Depending on b, for example?

Comment: The result should be a numerical value, it can be arccos(x) or arcsin(x), where x is any real number, between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Assume that the perpendicular from $B$ into the side $b$ hits $b$ at point $D$. Then, $\triangle BCD$ is a right triangle (since $\angle D = 90^\circ$) and in that triangle, the leg $BD$ is exactly half of the hypotenuse $BC$. If that's the case, you can find $\sin(C)$ from the definition and thus compute $\angle C$, and imply $\angle A$ from it.

If you do not know trigonometry, there is a classic result that in a $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ right triangle, the side opposite $30^\circ$ angle is exactly half the hypotenuse long.

---

**UPDATE**

With your understanding, denote $AD = h$ and observethat you can find the area of $\triangle ABC$ in two different ways:
$$
A_{\triangle ABC} = \frac{ac}{2} = \frac{bh}{2} \iff h = \frac{ac}{b}
$$
and so $\angle A = \arcsin(h/c) = \arcsin(a/b)$.

Comment: But how do you know that $BD=c_1$? The question says that $AD=c_1$. Or at least is that what I understand...

Comment: @AntonioJPan with your correction, may be simpler, please see update

Comment: But why the area is ac/2? B is not necessarily a right angle

Comment: @AntonioJPan you wrote that $ABC$ is a right triangle

Comment: Well, it wasn't me haha. I didn't see the first sentence of the statement, sorry.

Comment: I have been thinking about it for quote some time, but why is BD exactly half of the hipotenuse BC?

Comment: @developmentmentor because we are given $a = 2c_1$